# Set Dark Mode if User prefers-color-scheme: dark

Tags: javascript

I currently have a toggle button, which toggles the class `.dark-mode` on my `<body>`, then saving the preference into local storage.

Though, by default it's loading in the light theme.

I'm looking to make it so that if a customer is `prefers-color-scheme: dark`, it automatically switches to dark mode, if not, then it stays on light.

```
<script>
/* Dark Mode Selection */
// On page load set the theme.
    (function() {
    let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
    let element = document.body;
    element.classList.add(onpageLoad);
    document.getElementById("theme").textContent =
        localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light";
    })();



    function themeToggle() {
    let element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

    let theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    if (theme && theme === "dark-mode") {
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "");
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark-mode");
    }

    document.getElementById("theme").textContent = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    }

</script>
```

I'm unsure how to make it default to their preferred colour on first load.

Answer (score -1):

Simply reading [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) shows answer even without JS:

```
.day   { background: #eee; color: black; }
.night { background: #333; color: white; }

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .day.dark-scheme   { background:  #333; color: white; }
  .night.dark-scheme { background: black; color:  #ddd; }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  .day.light-scheme   { background: white; color:  #555; }
  .night.light-scheme { background:  #eee; color: black; }
}

.day, .night {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 7em;
  height: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```